# disable output from symfony2 command

Tags: doctrine-orm, symfony-2.1

I'm writing some unit tests and need to call some commands in the unit test in order to create a test database.  However, when I call the command it's dumping the notices to the screen.  Is there a way to shut this off?  I've tried to execute --quiet, but it doesn't suppress the notices.

```
$this->runConsole("doctrine:mongodb:schema:create", array("-q"=> null,"--env" => "test"));
```

....

```
protected function runConsole($command, Array $options = array())
{
    $options = array_merge($options, array('command' => $command));

    return $this->_application->run(new \Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArrayInput($options));
}
```

the notices i'm getting:

```
[2013-02-07 16:24:43] doctrine.INFO: MongoDB query: {"deleteIndexes":true,"db":"xxxxxx","collection":"xxxxxx} [] []
[2013-02-07 16:24:43] doctrine.INFO: MongoDB query: {"deleteIndexes":true,"db":"xxxxxx","collection":"xxxxxx"} [] []
[2013-02-07 16:24:43] doctrine.INFO: MongoDB query: {"deleteIndexes":true,"db":"xxxxxx","collection":"xxxxxx"} [] []
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `CommandTester` to test your command. You can read more about it here:

http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/console/introduction.html#testing-commands

Comment: sorry, i wasn't clear.  I don't need to test the command.. i'm writing tests that call commands to load some data.

Comment: oh, ok. But anyway - you shouldn't use your database (or any other data source) in your unit tests! If you use database it's no more unit test. I advise you to stub appropriate "data provider" in order to get any data you need. If you show the method that you want test maybe I can tell more

Comment: this is a functional test for my controller.  i want to make sure that the controller is storing data properly.  is there another way to test that?

Comment: functional test is different story. But still - why you do you want run symfony's command? Do you want reload database before tests? If so then consider use fixtures instead or reload database inside your test bootstrap. The third option is mock your document manager to avoid connect to database at all, and inject it into client's service container. IMO using commands for this purpose from test level is not very good idea.

Comment: so im using the commands to load my fixtures into a test database. I could call the fixtures directly, but I don't want to duplicate work.

Comment: so maybe good idea is load fixtures in your test bootstrap? you can read about it here: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/testing/bootstrap.html. If you want keep your way, look at this: https://gist.github.com/jakzal/1319290

Answer (score 0):

I added a config_test.yml in the app/config directory and added these lines (which are copied from my config_dev.yml):

```
monolog:
    handlers:
       main:
           type:  stream
           path:  "%kernel.logs_dir%/%kernel.environment%.log"
           level: debug
       firephp:
           type:  firephp
           level: info
```